# Array sorting error: " Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands"

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, timestamp

This is the code for sorting an array by the each cells in the tableView's timestamp.

```
self.ProjectsArray.sorted(by: { (project, project2) -> Bool in       
   return project.timestamp?.intValue < project2.timestamp?.intValue     
   })
```

Is there a better way to sort an array? What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to compare Optionals. You need to define how to compare the variables when one of them are `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**- According to your comments you want to sort in place, so I am updating to sort in place.

Your timestamp variable is an `Optional`, so you may be comparing `nil` to `nil`, or `nil` to an `Int`.  You can either unwrap these safely and provide a sort order in the case that one is nil, or you can use a nil-coalescing operator to treat `nil` value as some default Int like 0.  The two options look like this:

Optional unwrapping:

```
self.ProjectsArray.sort(by: { (project, project2) -> Bool in
    if let timestamp1 = project.timestamp, let timestamp2 = project2.timestamp {
       return timestamp1.intValue < timestamp2.intValue
    } else {
        //At least one of your timestamps is nil.  You have to decide how to sort here.
        return true
    }    
})
```

Nil-coalescing operators:

```
self.ProjectsArray.sort(by: { (project, project2) -> Bool in  
    //Treat nil values as 0s and sort accordingly     
    return (project.timestamp?.intValue ?? 0) < (project2.timestamp?.intValue ?? 0)     
})
```

Comment: Both the code "sections" you returned leaves a warning: "Result of call to 'sorted(by:)' is unused" @creeperspeak

Comment: Yes, because you are simply sorting an array without doing anything with it.  If you are trying to "sort in place" you should change `sorted(by` to `sort(by`, and that will sort the original array.  Otherwise, `sorted(by` returns a new, sorted version of the original array.

Comment: I'm honestly pretty confused with your code @creeperspeak, how should I proceed to have the array sorted after this block of code?

Comment: Change `sorted(by` to `sort(by`

Comment: I updated the example to provide this change for you.  I'm just trying to point out that there's a difference between using the `sorted` function and the `sort` function.